# Change resolution in wineconfig

Tags: wine

I used `wineconfig` for virtual window screen and selected 1024×768. Now I cannot change this resolution again, as when I start `wineconfig` again, because of the odd resolution the "Apply" portion goes below the screen. Is there any fix?

Answer (score 2):

With <kbd>TAB</kbd> button you can change focus, when it comes to *dpi* section press one time <kbd>TAB</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can change resolution of wine desktop from `user.reg`, it is usually located in `/home/<username>/.wine/user.reg`. There, find the line `"Default"="1024x768"` and change `1024x768` to other resolution like `1366x768`.

Comment: This option  `"Default"="1024x768"` not exist on my  `user.reg` file  should i add it .

Comment: @SalemF, did you set virtual desktop from `winecfg`? It will not exist if you did not set it.

Comment: I tried this command `wine explorer /desktop=WOW,1024x768 "/media/fun/wow/Wow.exe"` and it's worked, i added it to application launcher so I don't need to change `wine`configuration permanently